# grep not returning expected result with regex on xml

Tags: regex, grep, centos

I'm running a grep command on some xml, and it appears to be misinterpretting the regular expression I'm trying to use.

Here's the command

```
grep '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage.*?>' ./075679942012_ORIGNAL.xml
```

what appears to be happening is that the `?>` aspect of the regex seems to cause no matching rather than matching to the first occurence of `>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the text upto the first occurrence of `>` character then try the below command,

```
 grep -o '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage[^>]*>' file
```

If you want the whole line then remove `-o` parameter.

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa1.txt
<ernm:NewReleaseMessage blah> foo bar>
$ grep -o '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage[^>]*>' aa1.txt
<ernm:NewReleaseMessage blah>
```

`grep` with `-o` prints only the matched text.

`[^>]*` - Not of `>` character zero or more. So it matches upto the first occurance of `>` character.

Answer (score 2):

By default, grep uses *basic regular expression* and considers `?` as a literal question-mark. For it to be considered regular expression syntax, you need to escape that character.

```
grep '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage.*\?>' ./075679942012_ORIGNAL.xml
```

You can use the `-E` option which interprets the pattern as an *[extended regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html)*.

```
grep -E '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage.*?>' ./075679942012_ORIGNAL.xml
```

**Note:** This above will return the whole line that matches your pattern, if you only want the matched text, use the `-o` option which prints only the matched  parts of matching lines.

```
grep -o '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage.*\?>' ./075679942012_ORIGNAL.xml
```

OR

```
grep -Eo '<ernm:NewReleaseMessage.*?>' ./075679942012_ORIGNAL.xml
```